# Haproxy redirect www to non-www

Tags: haproxy

I'm currently using Haproxy to balance several express.js nodes. I know that it's possible to redirect using express.js, but I was hoping to do so with Haproxy.

I was wondering how I can do a permanent redirect from www.mysite.com to mysite.com?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

```
redirect prefix http://example.com code 301 if { hdr(host) -i www.example.com }
```

Please see the documentation of the [redirect prefix](http://cbonte.github.com/haproxy-dconv/configuration-1.4.html#4-redirect%20prefix) rule for more information.

If you are using a newer version of HAProxy, i.e. at least 1.6, you can use a more generic syntax which allows to redirect any host, not just explicitly named

```
http-request redirect prefix http://%[hdr(host),regsub(^www\.,,i)] code 301 if { hdr_beg(host) -i www. }
```

Here, we are using the [regsub](http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/configuration-1.6.html#7.3.1-regsub) filter to dynamically generate the correct hostname without the `www.` prefix.

In case you want to perform a redirect the other way around, i.e. to add a `www` if there is none already, the rule becomes simpler:

```
http-request redirect prefix http://www.%[hdr(host)] code 301 unless { hdr_beg(host) -i www. }
```

Comment: You should add `code 301` to the examples at the bottom for consistency with the first example