# Use haproxy to redirect *.domain1.com/* to *.domain2.com/*

Tags: server, load-balancing, haproxy

I am struggling with some HAproxy rules for a while with no luck unfortunately.

Let's say I have domain1.com and domain2.com. I want to redirect everything from domain1.com to domain2.com, including subdomains and parameters.

Ex:

- foo.domain1.com => foo.domain2.com
- foo.domain1.com/?bar => foo.domain2.com/?bar
- domain1.com/?bar => domain2.com/?bar
- etc

I've tried with `reqrep ^([^\ ]*\) (.*)domain1.com(.*) 1/ domain2.com\2` but it does not do the trick.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to to achieve that.

```
acl domain_redirect hdr_end(host) -i domain1.com
http-request set-var(req.new_host) req.hdr(host),regsub(domain1\.com$,domain2.com,i) if domain_redirect
http-request redirect prefix https://%[var(req.new_host)] code 301 if { var(req.new_host) -m found }
```

I think there's only one shortcoming in this solution: it seems to discard anchors from the URL. For example:

```
domain1.com?foo=bar#ze-anchor -> domain2.com?foo=bar
```

Answer (score -2):

Put this in your `frontend` block:

`redirect prefix http://domain2.com code 301 if { hdr(host) -i domain1.com }`.

Same answer as this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19826989/255523

Comment: This handles one of the cases only (domain1.com/?bar -> domain2.com/?bar).